# Why does my output change from military time to standard?

Tags: c#

Here's my input:

```
sw.WriteLine("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt} ", DateTime.Now + Convert.ToString(newurls[counter]));
```

and I get this output:

`4/4/2016 2:46:57 PM14751`

Then when I flip the two inputs like this:

```
sw.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(newurls[counter])  +  "{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt} ", DateTime.Now);
```

I get this output:

`1459104/04/2016 14:48:02 PM`

Note: `newurls[counter]` is changing all the time.

Back on point, I want it so that the DateTime now is in military time, but in front of `newurls[counter`. What I mean is, I want the output to be like this:

`04/04/2016 14:48:02 PM14591`

Why are the times switching back and forth from military and standard?

Comment: Have you tried `sw.Write("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt} ", DateTime.Now);sw.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(newurls[counter]));` EDIT: Igor's answer is better. Use that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sw.WriteLine("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt} ", DateTime.Now + Convert.ToString(newurls[counter]));
```

should probably be

```
sw.WriteLine("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt} {1}", DateTime.Now, Convert.ToString(newurls[counter]));
```

In the first instance you are converting the datetime to a string and then adding it to the Convert.ToString results. In the second instance you are converting it first with your formatter and then concatinating the strings.

In my change above I am adding a placeholder for your second parameter in the string as `{1}`, that is where the `Convert.ToString(newurls[counter])` will be placed. For more info see [Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

When you are adding:

> DateTime.Now + Convert.ToString(newurls[counter])

that's where you lose your date formating

I think what you want is:

> sw.WriteLine("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt} {1}", 
>   DateTime.Now , Convert.ToString(newurls[counter]));

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are dealing with is that you are dealing with two completely different formats and values.

In the first example, you are giving the string format:

```
"{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt} "
```

and then providing the value

```
DateTime.Now + Convert.ToString(newurls[counter])
```

The default `ToString()` implementation for a date is the short generic version.  Because parameter `0` is not a DateTime, the value is treated as a string.  You can verify this by simply writing:

```
 sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + Convert.ToString(newurls[counter]));
```

The solution is to treat the different components as separate items:

```
sw.WriteLine("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt} {1}",
    DateTime.Now,
    Convert.ToString(newurls[counter]));
```

You can now change the relationship of `{1}` and `{0}` to each other and get what you expect.  If you are using string formats, you should **never** need to use the `+` sign.  Simply write your values as a comma separated list and use number in the curly brackets refer to the individual paramters you are passing ing.  In this case, `DateTime.Now` was passed in first so we refer to it as `{0}`.  `Convert.ToString(newurls[counter])` was passed in second so we refer to it as `{1}`.